# Callback function not called?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have 2 callback functions in an Arduino file (.ino, c++):

```
void incomingPacket(const char* subject, const char* message){
  Serial.print("subject: ");
  Serial.println(subject);
  Serial.print("message: ");
  Serial.println(message);
}

void connectedProtocol(bool connected){
  if(connected){
    Serial.println("protocol server connected");  
  }else{
    Serial.println("protocol server disconnected");  
  }
}
```

And in my Arduino file I have a custom class `UDPProtocol protocol(Udp)` which calls the callback functions after certain events, like:

```
 _connectedcb(setTo);    //this calls connectedProtocol callback in Arduino from UDPProtocol class
```

This above works fine, it calls the callback function `connectedProtocol()` with correct boolean value. However, when trying to call `incomingPacket()` callback function, nothing happens in my Arduino file. Method that calls the callback:

```
//this is from UDPProtocol class
void UDPProtocol::readPacketContents(char* content){
        if(strlen(content)){                                //if content size is greater than 0
        const char* somemessage = "Hellomessage";
        const char* subject;
        const char* message;
        subject = &somemessage[0];                          //this depends on the actual format of udp packet
        message = &somemessage[1];
        _packetcb(subject,message);
        }
        _buffer[0] = 0;
    }
```

Whenever this method runs, callback is not called in Arduino. Even if I try to fake the message like:

```
void UDPProtocol::readPacketContents(char* content){
        if(strlen(content)){                                //if content size is greater than 0
            const char* somemessage = "Hellomessage";
            const char* subject;
            const char* message;
            subject = &somemessage[0];                          //this depends on the actual format of udp packet
            message = &somemessage[1];
            _packetcb(subject,message);
        }
        _buffer[0] = 0;
    }
```

Still nothing happens (if(strlen(content)) does equal true). Any suggestions?

EDIT:

UDPProtocol.h file:

```
typedef void (*PackedCallback)(const char* subject, const char* message);
PackedCallback _packetcb;
```

UDPProtocol.cpp file:

```
void UDPProtocol::setPacketCallback(PackedCallback func){
    this->_packetcb = func;
}
```

In Arduino.ino:

```
protocol.setPacketCallback(incomingPacket);    //defined in this question above
```

EDIT 2:

I created a gist with the full code:

https://gist.github.com/aliamid93/64ba2ed0e06b1f9b4401474646f8083e

Comment: `Serial` is not declared in the code you've shown. To me, this is a sign that we need more context.

Comment: @Chipster Serial is Arduinos way of writing from the arduino board to a "serial monitor" on the computer. See https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/ But if there is anything else I can provide let me know, please. Thanks.

Comment: Double check that you are assigning the correct callback functions to those events. It sounds like the code is calling default handlers rather than your code.

Comment: I guess, your problem is somehow related to `_packetcb` and you're hiding the relevant part.

Comment: @ChrisRyding I added some more code under EDIT

Comment: @datafiddler I added some more code under EDIT